# iOS - JSONSerialization VS JSONDecoder and usage

Tags: ios, json, swift, jsondecoder, json-serialization

So i am getting the follow json :

```
 {
"output": [
"{\"cameraIsOnboarded\" : true}"
 ],
"exit_code": 0
}
```

i tried to decode it with the model below:

```
struct CameraOnboard: Codable {

  var output: [Output]
  //var exit_code: Int?
 }

struct Output: Codable {

  var cameraIsOnboarded: Bool?
}
```

And then use it in my parser :

```
        let infoString = try JSONDecoder().decode(CameraOnboard.self, from: data)
```

but it craches.

Then i have tried to use JSONSerialization because  i thought i have a problem with the \"cameraIsOnboarded\" key, so i got from alamofire result string and tried the follow:

```
   let jsonData = data.data(using: .utf8)

    var dic: [String : Any]?
    do {
        dic = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData!, options: []) as? [String : Any]
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    print(dic!)
    if let outPutArr  = dic?["output"] as? NSArray {
        print(outPutArr)

        if let first = outPutArr.firstObject {
            print(first)

            //let val =  first["cameraIsOnboarded"]
           // print(val!)
        }
    }
```

so as above i dont no how to extract the value yet i print :

{"cameraIsOnboarded" : true}

if i do as follow:

```
  if let first = outPutArr.firstObject as? [String: Bool] {
            print(first)

            //let val =  first["cameraIsOnboarded"]
           // print(val!)
        }
```

it dosent step inside.

Thanks

Comment: Your JSON is weird. The value of `output` is an array of strings, not an array of dictionary. That's why your Codable attempt failed and why you are having trouble with JSONSerialization.

Comment: @rmaddy getting this JSON from the backend.
with JSONSerialization i am not success to extract the bool

Comment: Your backend needs to fix the JSON. `"{\"cameraIsOnboarded\" : true}"` is a string, not a dictionary. It should be `{"cameraIsOnboarded" : true}`

Comment: @rmaddy i know , but till they do that, how can i handle that?

Comment: One way is to convert the string to Data and pass that data to JSONSerialization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The json should look like ( Recommended)

```
{
    "output": {
        "cameraIsOnboarded" : true
    },
    "exit_code": 0
}
```

---

You can use this to handle current case

```
do {
   let  dic = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: str.data(using: .utf8)!, options: []) as! [String : Any]
    if let outPutArr  = dic["output"] as? [String] {
         if let first = outPutArr.first {
           let dic = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: (first as! String).data(using: .utf8)!, options: []) as! [String : Bool]
            print(dic["cameraIsOnboarded"])
        }
    } 
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
```

Comment: I know , but it isnt so how can i handle it

Comment: Thanks!
the JSONSerialization of the object helped with it!